# How to hyperlink input files/labels

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am using a star rating system for email templates. Some examples I found allow you to only select the rating, but I would like to hyperlink each star so that it takes you to a different link depending on the star that is clicked. Is this possible? I tried to hyperlink the entire input type but it removes the star icon.

Here is the CSS and HTML, as well as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/pz62gcq0/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset= "UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Star rating using pure CSS</title>
</head>
<style>
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.rate {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    float: left;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label {
    float:right;
    width:1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#ccc;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:before {
    content: '★ ';
}
.rate > input:checked ~ label {
    color: #ffc700;    
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rate:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
    color: #deb217;  
}
.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
    color: #c59b08;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="rate">
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" /><label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" /><label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" /><label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" /><label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" /><label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Without JS and retaining your current markup, I don't see this as possible using valid HTML - having interactive content (eg. an `<input>`) as a child of an anchor tag [doesn't conform to the W3 spec](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element), which would probably behave inconsistently across browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/v0qrgopz/1/

I've converted the inputs to links so that clicking on them takes you somewhere. I've used Flexbox to reverse the order of them so that the selector `a:hover ~ a` works.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I see that you jsfiddle is exactly the same as mine, so maybe you forgot to save it?

Comment: @Yevgen - You're right. I don't use fiddle often. Link updated.

Comment: Perfect! You also removed all the junk I did not need so it's really simple now and works. I just increased the font size of the stars a little and removed the underline: https://jsfiddle.net/v0qrgopz/3/

Answer (score 2):

You could use some inline JavaScript via the onclick event attribute. Inside each of your input tags include the attribute:

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com')"
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/KyleVassella/pz62gcq0/2/

Insert whatever link you like. This could also be done using a separate JS file if you don't want to use inline.

Comment: Thanks. This is very good to know for future reference, but since I will be using this in an email template, I prefer not to use any JS if there are other options.